# Function composition vs single function

Tags: functions, category-theory, function-and-relation-composition

For I'm learning Category Theory, sometimes I encounter people treating function composition like if it's equal to *another* single function *(i.e. not just results the same!)*. As an example, below I quoted the proof from *Conceptual Mathematics: A first introduction to Categories*.

Note: authors does not just equate result of $x$ to $s∘y$, but rather say that $x$ *is* $s∘y$, that's the gist of the proof. But the assumption would wreak havoc onto commutative diagrams! I.e. if they're the same arrows, $T = B$ must be the same objects too *($y$ becomes identity, $x$ must be $s$)*; and we could *any* commutative diagram collapse to just a pair of objects, killing out e.g. products.

I'd think authors misunderstand something, but I encountered alike treatment before in other sources, so perhaps it's mine incomprehension. What do I miss?

> **Proposition 1**: If a map $A \xrightarrow{f}B$ has a section, then for any $T$ and for any map $T \xrightarrow{y} B$ there exists a map $T \xrightarrow{x}A$ for which $f ∘ x = y$.
>
> **Proof:** The assumption means that we have a map $s$ for which $f ∘ s = 1_B$. Thus for any given map $y$ as below
>
> $\hskip3in$ [image]
>
> we see that we could define a map $x$ with at least the correct domain and codomain by taking the composite $s$ following $y$
>
> $$x=s∘y$$
>
> Does this map x actually satisfy the required equation? Calculating
>
> $$f ∘ x = f ∘ (s∘y) = (f∘s)∘y=1_B ∘ y = y$$
>
> we see that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I encounter people treating function composition like if it's equal to another single function (i.e. not just results the same!).

Yes, this is precisely how composition of morphisms works.

> I.e. if they're the same arrows, $T = B$ must be the same objects too

No. $s \circ y$ is a morphism from $T$ to $A$. $x$ is also a morphism from $T$ to $A$.  So everything is fine.

Comment: I see… So, all functions, compound or not, given it has the same result and the same domain'n'codomain, considered to be the same. I.e. internal structure of the function, its implementation, doesn't matter, there's *only* two conditions to hold for function to be considered absolutely equal to another one.

Comment: Make sure to distinguish between *functions* (morphisms in the category of sets) and morphisms in general.  A morphism in general doesn't have "results."  Functions, by definition, are simply an assignment of particular inputs to particular outputs.  There are generally many ways of describing the same function.

Comment: Ah, I see, I've heard of morphisms not being functions, though the last time I did read an example, I didn't have enough knowledge to completely embrace.